# php smarty2 json_decode return different value

Tags: php, json, smarty2

We just move our web server to AWS EC2 instance and got the strange issue.

We use smarty2 and php5.3 on Centos 6 on both EC2 and our old dedicated server (php.ini and httpd configuration are moved to EC2 too)
Here is the json data and code behind:

> $json = "{    "crawl_url": "https://google.com/",  "status": "OK", }"
>
> $smarty->assign("data", $json);

template view:

> {assign var=tmp value=$data|json_decode:1}
>
> {$tmp.status}

Result:

> on old dedicated server: it display "OK" as expected
>
> on EC2 server: it display "{" // not sure why

Please note that magic quote disabled on both server and 2 server use the same code base

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in your code.

Try this code:

PHP:

```
<?php

    $json = [
        "crawl_url" => "https://google.com/",
        "status" => "OK"
    ];

    $smarty->assign("data", json_encode($json));

?>
```

Smarty:

```
{assign var=tmp value=$data|json_decode:1}

{$tmp|var_dump}
{$tmp.status|var_dump}
```